# Securely running user's code

Tags: security, eval, user-defined-functions

I am looking to create an AI environment where users can submit their own code for the AI and let them compete. The language could be anything, but something easy to learn like JavaScript or Python is preferred.

Basically I see three options with a couple of variants:

1. Make my own language, e.g. a JavaScript clone with only very basic features like variables, loops, conditionals, arrays, etc. This is a *lot* of work if I want to properly implement common language features.

   1.1 Take an existing language and strip it to its core. Just remove lots of features from, say, Python until there is nothing left but the above (variables, conditionals, etc.). Still a lot of work, especially if I want to keep up to date with upstream (though I just could also just ignore upstream).
2. Use a language's built-in features to lock it down. I know from PHP that you can disable functions and searching around, similar solutions seem to exist for Python (with lots and lots of caveats). For this I'd need to have a good understanding of all the language's features and not miss anything.

   2.1. Make a preprocessor that rejects code with dangerous stuff (preferably whitelist based). Similar to option 1, except that I only have to implement the parser and not implement all features: the preprocessor has to *understand* the language so that you can have variables named "eval" but not call the function named "eval". Still a lot of work, but more manageable than option 1.

   2.2. Run the code in a very locked-down environment. Chroot, no unnecessary permissions... perhaps in a virtual machine or container. Something in that sense. I'd have to research how to achieve this and how to make it give me the results in a secure way, but that seems doable.
3. Manually read through all code. Doable on a small scale or with moderators, though still tedious and error-prone (I might miss stuff like `if (user.id = 0)`).

The way I imagine 2.2 to work is like this: run both AIs in a virtual machine (or something) and constrain it to communicate with the host machine only (no other Internet or LAN access). Both AIs run in a separate machine and communicate with each other (well, with the playing field, and thereby they see each other's positions) through an API running on the host.

Option 2.2 seems the most doable, but also relatively hacky... I let someone's code loose in a virtualized or locked down environment, hoping that that'll keep them in while giving them free game to DoS or break out of the environment. Then again, most other options are not much better.

---

**TL;DR:** in essence my question is: *how do I let people give me 'logic' for an AI (which I think is most easily done using code) and then run that without compromising the functionality of the system?* There must be at least 2 AIs working on the same playing field.

Comment: Doing it at the language level is too error-prone. Just about any feature of a language can be misused. Even something as seemingly harmless as regular expressions can starve a system for CPU resources using [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). A container can solve a lot of these issues. Using something like Docker, you can specify CPU quotas so no single container can starve the CPU. You can also run the container as a user that has limited disk access.

Comment: @vcsjones Good advice, please post as answer. To clarify, you mean any language-based option, including writing my own language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just a plugin system, so researching how others implement plugins is a good starting point. In particular, I'd look at web browsers like Chrome and Safari and their plugin systems.

A common theme in modern plugins systems is process isolation. Ideally you should run the plugin in its own process space in a sandbox. In OS X look at XPC, which is designed explicitly for this problem. On Linux (or more portably), I would probably look at NaCl (Native Client). The JVM is also designed to provide sandboxing, and offers a rich selection of languages. (That said, I don't personally consider the JVM a very strong sandbox. It's had a history of security problems.)

In general, my preference on these kinds of projects is a language-agnostic API. I most often use REST APIs (or "REST-like"). This allows the plugin to be highly restricted, while not restricting the language choice. I like simple HTTP for communications whenever possible because it has rich support in numerous languages, so it puts little restriction on the plugin. In fact, given your description, you wouldn't even have to run the plugin on your hardware (and certainly not on the main server). Making the plugins remote clients removes many potential concerns.

But ultimately, I think something like your "2.2" is the right direction.

Comment: I thought of an API. The reason I (in hindsight, incorrectly) immediately rejected the idea of a public API where people connect their bots to was latency. Solve one headache; start another (I've been at realtime multiplayer games before, it's pretty difficult to get right). But perhaps by running the code in virtualized environments and letting it connect to an API on the same physical host (or LAN), I can circumvent the latency issue. Hmm. Upvote for sure, perhaps accepted answer later. Thanks!